# blocking facebook.com outside facebook.com domain

Tags: privoxy

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/facebookblocker/

So are there any ways to block facebook.com outside the facebook.com domain?

I need a souliton that's not "webbrowser related" - no Add-on, so e.g.: a Privoxy rule.
It would still not work on HTTPS sites, only on HTTP, ok, but I still need this rule, but I don't have a clue what it is. Does anybody has?

Thank you!

UPDATE
on a desktop PC/Fedora 15

So I don't want to block facebook.com. I just don't want that that e.g.: if there is a foo.org that has a

Comment: This question doesn't have nearly enough information to solve. You don't mention your os or browser, what your network situation is, whether you have access to a router or DNS configs, whether you are blocking for one for a user, a computer, a network, or what. Please edit the question and be a lot more specific or it is likely to get closed as unanswerable.

Comment: Please join to this discussion http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24694/privoxy-blocking-twitter-facebook-and-google-outside-of-their-domains-https (or continue it here)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to your firewall, You can just block Facebook's prefixes.
You can find out their ASN from traceroute:

```
$  traceroute -n -A www.facebook.com
....
14  4.69.149.82 [AS3356]  630.713 ms  633.180 ms 4.69.149.146 [AS3356]  629.633 ms
15  4.53.112.58 [AS3356]  578.959 ms  580.703 ms  579.624 ms
16  204.15.20.120 [AS32934/AS10753]  577.604 ms  557.247 ms  636.807 ms
17  74.119.76.67 [AS32934]  633.454 ms 74.119.76.186 [AS32934]  602.556 ms  603.583 ms
18  74.119.76.197 [AS32934]  634.461 ms 74.119.76.205 [AS32934]  634.431 ms 74.119.77.55 [AS32934]  702.079 ms
19  69.63.190.10 [AS32934/AS10753]  701.423 ms  700.644 ms  700.937 ms
```

Which you can verify with tools such as [these](http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/ip-to-asn.html)

```
$ dig +short AS32934.asn.cymru.com TXT
"32934 | US | arin | 2004-08-24 | FACEBOOK - Facebook, Inc."
```

Then you'd get their prefixes using a [lookup service](https://www.dan.me.uk/bgplookup?asn=32934)

```
$ lynx --dump https://www.dan.me.uk/bgplookup?asn=32934 2>&1 | grep AS32934
   IPv4 Prefixes seen at AS32934:
     204.15.20.0/22       [AS32934]
     2620:0:1c00::/40     [AS32934]
     66.220.144.0/21      [AS32934]
     66.220.152.0/21      [AS32934]
     66.220.159.0/24      [AS32934]
     69.171.224.0/20      [AS32934]
     69.171.239.0/24      [AS32934]
     69.171.240.0/20      [AS32934]
     69.171.255.0/24      [AS32934]
     69.63.176.0/21       [AS32934]
     69.63.184.0/21       [AS32934]
     74.119.76.0/22       [AS32934]
```

You can then feed the prefixes into your firewall.

Of course, If I am a determined user, I could use any of the free proxies out there rendering this whole post moot.

Answer (score 0):

One time-honored way of blocking access to remote sites is by putting "fake" entries (usually 127.0.0.1) in the hosts file.

In short, edit /etc/hosts and add entries like this:

```
127.0.0.1    facebook.com
172.0.0.1    apps.facebook.com
```

FMI on this trick, [read this](http://osxdaily.com/2007/03/19/block-access-to-specified-sites-by-modifying-etchosts/); for more ideas of blocking, [read that](http://www.wikihow.com/Block-MySpace-from-a-Home-Network).