# How to block the Google Analytics Script using Privoxy

Tags: regular-expression, privoxy

***Related subject:** [Privoxy: blocking twitter, facebook and google outside of their domainslr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24694/privoxy-blocking-twitter-facebook-and-google-outside-of-their-domains-https)*

Never mind what rule I am adding to the default.filter file, I don't make it to block these scripts.

```
<!--Google Analytics Script Start -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-649033-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
  })();

</script>
<!--Google Analytics Script End -->
```

So far I have tried these rules:

```
s|<script [^>]*(google-analytics.com/ga.js).*>(.*</script>)|<!-- utma Cookies-->|gis
s|<script [^>]*(google-analytics).*>(.*</script>)|<!-- utma Cookies-->|gis
s|<script [^>]*(google-analytics*).*>(.*</script>)|<!-- utma Cookies-->|gis
s|<script [^>]*(google-analytics*).*</script>)|<!-- utma Cookies-->|gis
s|<script [^>]*(analytics*).*</script>)|<!-- utma Cookies-->|gis
```

What is needed to be done to erase the code?

*P.S
I am also using this in my user.action file*

```
{+block{No Bull!}}
.google-analytics./*
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to block loading of only `http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js`, open your **user.action** file, locate the section that has { +block-as-image } at the start and put `.google-analytics.com/ga.js` on a line of its own after { +block-as-image }. Since many sites just use `ga.js`, you may prefer just `/.*ga.js`.

In other words,

```
{ +block-as-image }
#.google-analytics.com/ga.js
#/.*ga.js
```

Uncomment the one you want to use. Delete the other. The problem with a short pattern is the chance of unintended blocking. The other point is that Privoxy won't block content on **https** sites.